# WebSphere logging to customized files

Tags: logging, websphere

We have a web app application which we need to log the errors that occurs to and AppNameError.log

Based on what I read:

http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/#!/SSAW57_8.0.0/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/info/ae/ae/rtrb_enabletrc.html?cp=SSAW57_8.0.0%2F1-16-5-1103

http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/#!/SSHRKX_8.5.0/mp/trouble/adsyslog.dita

My understanding is that I can log to SystemOut.log or trace.log.

Does WebSphere provide a mechanism to log to customized files that I can create in the server directory.?

Can I log based on each application in my worklight server?

For example:

MyProject1 >>>>>> MyProject1.log

MyProject2 >>>>>> MyProject2.log

WebSphere version 8.5.5.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have several options, which more or less can help you in archiving desired result.

1) WebSphere is using JUL and Jakarta Commons internally, so you can customize it but its a bit complex. See [Adding logging and tracing to your application](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/ae/ttrb_addtrace.html?cp=SSAW57_8.5.5%2F1-13-2-5&lang=en)

2) Use external logger like log4j - see some more basic info here - [WAS Logging - Java Util Logging and Log4j](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4826774/was-logging-java-util-logging-and-log4j?rq=1)

3) Use new HPEL logging available since WAS 8.0. Although it doesn't create logs for each application, you can any time query log messages for the given application using logViewer, like this (you can also use tail like behavior using `-monitor` flag):

```
logViewer -includeExtensions appName=PlantsByWebSphere
```

It also allows you to do some more nice things like for example display only messages from given thread, etc. And is fully integrated in the admin console.

I'd recommend at least trying it, maybe it will fulfill your needs.

Some more details here:

- [High Performance Extensible Logging (HPEL)](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/ae/ctrb_HPELOverview.html?lang=en)
- [LogViewer command-line tool usage and options](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/ae/rtrb_logviewer.html)
- [Log viewer in the console](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEQTP_8.0.0/com.ibm.websphere.base.doc/info/aes/ae/utrb_viewHPELconsole.html?cp=SSEQTP_8.0.0%2F1-15-5-488)

Comment: Thank A lot for you answer, I will review with my PaaS team to see if we can get this done.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you can change where the standard logs go, but cannot write to multiple logs based on some filter criteria.  To do that, I think you'd have to build your own logging utility into your app.

If your app began each log entry with a tag like "myAppLogEntry:" then it would be easy to extract those entries out of the standard logs.